# Are there any good SPfx tutorials, guides and examples?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, spfx-extensions

Since SharePoint 2019 doesn't come with certain features out of the box, eg. Column headers that stay in place while scrolling, I am in the process of learning SharePoint framework.

Are there any good resources out there that can guide me with learning SPFX?  I've used Pluralsight and Microsoft docs - they are good for basic development.  I need more intermediate stuff.

I need to be able to build in-depth Web Parts and extensions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft documentation is a very helpful and good resource to get started with: [SharePoint Framework Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

- Another Microsoft official good resource for SPFx learning is [YouTube tutorials](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_O2Re5uRLoo).
- There are many SPFx web parts and extensions samples developed by community on GitHub. You can can download them, use as it is if they fulfil your requirements or you can enhance them as per your requirements. Those are great samples, by looking at them you can understand how others are using SPFx.

1. [SPFx webpart samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts)
2. [SPFx extensions samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions)

**Other resources**:

1. [Tutorials in hand](https://tutorialsinhand.com/tutorials/sharepoint-framework-spfx-tutorial/spfx-basics/sharepoint-framework-tutorial.aspx)
2. There are many blogs/articles on C# Corner and other blog sites. When you will start developing you can search for specific information and you will get many related results on internet that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good samples in the github. I believe this would help you learn more about spfx.

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/all/